# How to receive uploaded files as array

Tags: go

How to receive multipart form where the files are sent as an array `<input type="file" name="files[]">` ?

This returns an empty result

```
fhs := r.MultipartForm.File["files"]
fmt.Printf("Files: %v", fhs)
```

Is it possible to list all input/field keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [ParseMultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm) before using the request's [MultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.MultipartForm) field.

Get the slice of files for the form field named `files[]` using this code:

```
fhs := r.MultipartForm.File["files[]"]
```

List all values and files by ranging over the maps and slices:

```
for k, vs := range r.MultipartForm.Value {
    for _, v := range vs {
        fmt.Printf("value %s: %s\n", k, v)
    }
}
for k, fs := range r.MultipartForm.File {
    for _, f := range fs {
        fmt.Printf("file %s: %s\n", k, f.Filename)
    }
}
```

Comment: (The `Println`s here should be `Printf`s)